# How to logout as soon as sharing a content via Facebook Android SDK 4?

Tags: android, facebook

I tried 3 different ways to share a content from an Android app. Whenever I succeeded, LoginManager.logOut() did not work.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
    Log.d("FaebookShare", "success");
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
    Profile.setCurrentProfile(null);
}
```

I should be logged out as soon as I share a content. Because my app will be a kiosk app.

What is the true way to do that?

Comment: _“Because my app will be a kiosk app”_ – not a good idea; it is highly likely that Facebook’s security algorithms will find a large amount of users logging in on the same device in quick succession suspicious. As a result, users will get asked to perform additional validation steps, and it is also possible that the app will get blocked automatically.

Comment: Much better to let users use their own devices and you just use Device Login